# What to do if partial integration yields $\infty-\infty$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, expected-value, logistic-regression

I have an integral where partial integration yields

$$\begin{aligned}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\underbrace{f(x)}_{=u}~\underbrace{\log\left(1+\exp\left(x\right)\right)}_{=V}~\mathrm{d}x 
&= \left[UV\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}Uv~\mathrm{d}x \\ 
&= \left[F(x)\log\left(1+\exp\left(x\right)\right)\right]_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}F(x)\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(-x\right)}~\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \infty-\infty \end{aligned}$$

where $f(x)$ is a pdf and $F(x)$ is a CDF. Numerically, the integral $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)\log\left(1+\exp\left(x\right)\right)~\mathrm{d}x$ always yields nice solutions. Is there also a way to fix this problem?

Comment: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty=\lim_{M,N\to\infty}\int_{-M}^N$

Comment: Integration by parts is not applicable here. Also, you did not differentiate $\log (1+e^{x})$ correctly.

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy: Sorry, sign was missing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V(x)=\log(1+\exp(x))$ is lovely and bounded for $x<0$. For $x>0$
$$V(x)=\log(1+\exp(x))=x+\log(\exp(-x)+1)=x+V(-x).$$
Then
$$\int_0^\infty f(x)V(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty xf(x)\,dx+\int_0^\infty V(-x)f(x)\,dx$$
and
$$\int_{-\infty}^0 f(x)V(x)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^0V(x)f(x)\,dx.$$
Therefore
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)V(x)\,dx=\int_0^\infty xf(x)\,dx
+\int_{-\infty}^\infty V(-|x|)f(x)\,dx.$$
The final integral above is nice and always converges. The integral of $xf(x)$
may or may not converge, but certainly does when the associated random variable
$X$ has $E(|X|)<\infty$. It will diverge if say $X$ is a Cauchy RV.